# Is Google Chrome History stored locally?

Tags: google-chrome

I came to know that chrome saves history somewhere in C:/Users//AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/UserData/Default

So I wanted to ask whether it's enough to delete history and cache normally through Chrome, or should I delete that file named 'History' in the Default folder as well?

Thanks!

Comment: In order to determine if clearing the local files is enough, to clear your browser history, you have to indicate if you are syncing your browser history to your Google Account.

Comment: Really sorry for replying so late. No, I am not signed in to Chrome, and my web activity is paused.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting history through Chrome and deleting the 'History' file do the same thing.

Deleting history through Chrome will clear all data stored in the file and if you delete the file, Chrome will create a new empty file upon next start.

So, clearing history through Chrome is enough and there's no need to delete any of the files in the Chrome folder.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! It looks to me like the `history` file is wiped clean when you clear your history.

If you want to double-check, the `history` file is a database that can be opened with [SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) browser. The table is `urls`. Comment if you need detailed instructions.